# Wolfram Alpha Error

Tags: windows, macros, speech, wolframalpha

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<speechMacros>
<command>
<listenFor>What is [...]</listenFor>
<speak>Ok sir one moment, my databases for a possible answer.</speak>
<waitFor seconds="3" />
<run command="http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i={[...]}" />


<script language="JScript">
<![CDATA[
try
{ 
var Wolframtext = ("{[...]}");

var xml_doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); 
xml_doc.async = false; 
xml_doc.load("http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i="+Wolframtext+"&format=xml&limit=1");


var tmp = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName("Description").item(0).text;
}

catch(err)
{
{
 tmp = "Sadly i don't know anything about that";
}
}

Application.Speak(tmp);
]]>
</script>


</command>



<Signature>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</Signature>
</speechMacros>
```

When I run this Macro for wikipedia, it works like a charm, But I cannot get it to configure to wolfram, and read the results in the same way.

I am just trying to get it to read the page results, other than that everything is working fine, it is bringing up the search in my browser, just not reading it.  Any help would be amazing

Comment: Probably you want to modify var tmp = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName("Description").item(0).text;
 to point to a real result returned by Wolfram, this path in xml document might not exist.

Comment: I actually figured it out using this

Comment: `xml_doc.load("http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?appid=xxxxx9-  `   `xxxxxxxxinput="+vsearch+"&format=plaintext"); `

just have to figure it out for google api.  It's easier to figure it out with macros for now.  I want to build it into an application of my own eventually but this helps to learn some syntax.  I want to eventually have a desktop/app version that i built on my own, but with databases. I find it useless if the same question is asked that it has to search everytime.  would love to see to eventually have it learn to formulate its own responses instead of predefined ones.